# How to generate coverage for node app using istanbul and jasmine?

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, istanbul

Currently i have a package.json with this info:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "babel-node test/jasmine-runner.js",
  "coveralls": "istanbul cover babel-node test/jasmine-runner.js && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js && rm -rf ./coverage"
}
```

i have code in ES6 and also my test are written in ES6 i run the test with a runner file jasmine-runner.js that contain this info:

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
var noop = function() {};

var jrunner = new Jasmine();
jrunner.configureDefaultReporter({print: noop});    // remove default reporter logs
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());   // add jasmine-spec-reporter
jrunner.loadConfigFile('test/support/jasmine.json');
jrunner.execute();
```

and after i run

```
npm run coveralls
```

i have this log:

```
15 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 1.767 seconds
No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information
cat: ./coverage/lcov.info: No such file or directory
[error] "2016-07-06T20:29:05.918Z"  'error from lcovParse: ' 'Failed to parse string'
[error] "2016-07-06T20:29:05.920Z"  'input: ' ''
[error] "2016-07-06T20:29:05.921Z"  'error from convertLcovToCoveralls'
```